# How to destroy a demonic amulet?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

In the monster manual (p.51), it mentions that demons have been known to create amulets which allow them to reform at a time and place of their choosing. If this amulet it destroyed, it is stuck in the abyss for a year and a day.

From this, I assume it can be destroyed, but are there any rules, for 5e D&D or another edition that describe what it would take to destroy the amulet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat it like an artifact

Since you asked for previous edition lore, p. 164 of the 1e AD&D DMG had a table with 8 ways to destroy an artifact, each of which had multiple sub-steps.  A few of the ways are extracted here to illustrate the point:

> 1. Melt it in the furnace/pit/fire where it was created.
> 2. Cause it to be devoured by an ancient dragon turtle
> 3. Crushed by ... the Gates of Hell, the Cornerstone of the World, the heel of a God, the foot of a humble ant
> 4. Expose it to the light of ... The Sun ... The Truth ...
> 5. Cause it to be immersed in the blood of Tiamat, the brain fluids of Bahamut, or the ichor of Juiblex.
> 6. Immerse it in The Well of Life ... River Styx ... River of Flame ...

The idea is for the DM to set up an unusual or difficult destruction mechanism.  If you feel that a demon's amulet is not quite as powerful as an artifact, then adapt the method to something slightly less difficult.  (The brain fluids of Bahamut are not easy to get ahold of ...)

The key is to fit the destruction method to something that is the opposite of, or opposed to, the demon in question.

---

FWIW, the 1e AD&D monster manual had an almost identical entry regarding demon amulets (p. 16).  None of the old Dragon mag articles I still have seems to have addressed the details of "how" to destroy such an amulet.  It was left up to the DM's discretion.

Answer (score 1):

### It's up to the DM

According to [this Sage Advice](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/12/02/how-would-one-destroy-a-magical-item/),

> Magic items tend to be resilient, but they are not indestructible. The DM can make it easy or hard. An acid pit might work!

The DMG (pg. 141) states

> Thanks to a combination of careful crafting and magical reinforcement, a magic item is at least as durable as a nonmagical item of its kind. Most magic items, other than potions and scrolls, have resistance to all damage. Artifacts are practically indestructible.

As far as I can find (and remember), the rules only say that magic items might be more durable than regular items, but don't give positive guidance on what **can** destroy them. The DM will have to come up with rules for that. It looks like possibilities range from "break like a normal object" to "totally indestructible".

Comment: Thank you, as the DM I will have to give it a think then.

Comment: You can also consider a specific sidequest or somesuch. Not making it easy, but not indestructible either. Like a ring that you could throw down into a specific volcano that destroys it.